# How can I select hidden fields by type and value using a jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery

I need a Jquery selector to select hidden fields by type and value

Something like this.

```
$('input[type="hidden" value="25"]')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('input[type="hidden"][value="25"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type=hidden][value=25]')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input:not(visible)[value=25]')
```